# Adding up hours from mysql database and then adding them to HTML table via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

As you can probably tell I'm poor at using mysql with PHP!  So here is my problem:

I have a mysql table named *TimeRecords* with the following columns: ID, Date, StartTime, EndTime, Break, and Location.

I have a table that displays that info using this SELECT

```
$result = mysql_query("
        SELECT * FROM TimeRecords
        WHERE Date
        BETWEEN '{$CurrentYear}-{$CurrentMonth}-1'
        AND '{$CurrentYear}-{$CurrentMonth}-31'
    ");
```

and this this code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Location:</th>
        <th>Date:</th>
        <th>Start:</th>
        <th>End:</th>
        <th>Break?</th>
        <th>Total Hours</th>
    </tr>

    <?php 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>". $row['Location'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>". $row['Date'] . "</td>";

                echo "<td>" . date("h:i A", ($row['StartTime'])) . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . date("h:i A", ($row['EndTime'])) . "</td>";

                echo "<td>";

                if ($row['Break']==1){
                    echo "Yes";
                }
                else {
                    echo "No";
                }
                echo "</td>";

            echo "</tr>";
        }


?>
</table>
```

How do I create another  in the table that will subtract the EndTime and StartTime to get the total hours worked for the day?

From what I understand I can grab that information using this SELECT:

```
$TimeWorked = mysql_query("
        SELECT ((EndTime - StartTime)/60/60) AS TimeWorked
        FROM TimeRecords
        ")
```

but I am not sure what I am supposed to do to display that within the loop.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Somehow I would need to call the second SELECT query but I am not sure how I would do that from the first loop.

Comment: Insert `, ((EndTime - StartTime)/60/60) AS TimeWorked` after the `*` in your first and only needed query. Then fetch that value with `$row['TimeWorked']` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$result = mysql_query("
        SELECT a.*, ((a.EndTime - a.StartTime)/3600) AS TotalHours FROM TimeRecords a
        WHERE Date
        BETWEEN '{$CurrentYear}-{$CurrentMonth}-1'
        AND '{$CurrentYear}-{$CurrentMonth}-31'
    ");
```

See if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much!  It worked like a charm.  but what does the "a" in a.* and a.StartTime etc mean?

Comment: Syntax to refer to the table `TimeRecords`. It is usually only necessary if you are pulling data from multiple tables (so not really necessary here), but it is reflex for me to add them.

Answer (score 0):

```
$starttime = $row['StartTime']
$endtime = $row['EndTime']
echo "<td>" . date("h:i A", ($starttime)) . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . date("h:i A", ($endtime)) . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . ($endtime - $starttime)/3600 . "</td>";
```

I'm not completely sure I know what you mean but would that work for you?

Comment: I tried that first and it works, but later on I am going to create a cell that will total all the hours worked and that is too much work to do solely in PHP.  That's kinda why I need mysql to do the work.  Thanks though!